# Configure Hammerjs events with angular2

Tags: angular, events, hammer.js, gestures

How can I configure hammerjs events in angular2?

To use hammerjs events with angular2 I just have to include events on my html like this:

```
<div (press)="onLongPress($event)"></div>
```

In this case (**press**) will have time of 251 milliseconds, by default.
[Hammerjs press event documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-press/)

How do I configure this time to have different value?

Comment: How do you include hammerjs in your HTML page?

Answer (score 13):

With Angular 2.0.1, there's actually a direct way to configure hammerjs:

```
// app.module.ts

import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig  {
  overrides = <any>{
      // override hammerjs default configuration
      'pan': {threshold: 5},
      'swipe': {
           velocity: 0.4,
           threshold: 20,
           direction: 31 // /!\ ugly hack to allow swipe in all direction
      }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ...],
  declarations: [ ... ],
  bootstrap:    [ ... ],
  providers:    [ { 
                    provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, 
                    useClass: MyHammerConfig 
                } ]
})
```

Note that I'm using a hack to allow swipe in all direction by using the current value of Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL. Though that value might not change for a while, I'll update this post as soon as someone whispers a way to access Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL value directly from the app module.

Comment: You just need to `import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';` and then you can 
`'swipe': { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL }` ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's not something easy since it's internally handled by the CustomHammerGesturesPlugin class. I see two approaches:

- **Provide your own Hammer plugin** and register it. When the `Hammer` object is instantiated, you need to provide your configuration as second parameter:

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class CustomHammerGesturesPlugin extends HammerGesturesPlugin {
    addEventListener(element: HTMLElement, eventName: string, handler: Function): Function {
      var zone = this.manager.getZone();
      eventName = eventName.toLowerCase();

      return zone.runOutsideAngular(function() {
        // Creating the manager bind events, must be done outside of angular
        var mc = new Hammer(element); // <-------
        mc.get('pinch').set({enable: true});
        mc.get('rotate').set({enable: true});
        var handler = function(eventObj) { zone.run(function() { handler(eventObj); }); };
        mc.on(eventName, handler);
        return () => { mc.off(eventName, handler); };
      });
    }
  }
  ```

  Since the `HammerGesturesPlugin` provider is automatically register when using the `bootstrap` function, you need to use this code to bootstrap your application (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/platform/browser.ts#L110 and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser_common.ts#L79):

  ```
  platform(BROWSER_PROVIDERS).application(appProviders).bootstrap(appComponentType);
  ```
- A workaround could be to **intercept the instantiation** of the `Hammer` object (see [Can I intercept a function called directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406467/can-i-intercept-a-function-called-directly)):

  ```
  <script>
    window.TargetHammer = window.Hammer;
    window.Hammer = function() {
      var mc = new TargetHammer(arguments[0]);
      mc.get('press').set({
        time: 1000
      });
      return mc;
    }
  </script>
  ```

  See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/eBBC9d?p=preview.

Otherwise I don't know which version of Angular2 you use but there is a problem with Hammer events (beta.0 seems to be okay):

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6993

Answer (score 1):

In order to configure Hammer.js events you can use [recognizer](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-press/) (options for the event). This can be used in a directive as shown here:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {Gesture} from 'ionic-angular/gestures/gesture';
declare var Hammer: any

@Directive({
  selector: '[spLongPress]'
})
export class LongPressDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  el: HTMLElement;
  pressGesture: Gesture;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pressGesture = new Gesture(this.el, {
      recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Press, { time: 500 }]
      ]
    });
    this.pressGesture.listen();
    this.pressGesture.on('press', e => {
      console.log('pressed!!');
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.pressGesture.destroy();
  }
}
```

This fires the event after 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

After one of the pull requests to angular, now there is way to override configuration of hammerjs.

I have answered in other thread about how to override default config variables of hammerjs in angular2 / typescript way.

By this method you can override all default settings and there is no need to instantiate custom HammerJs plugin.

Here is link to answer:

[Using mobile events in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728451/using-mobile-events-in-angular2/38386069#38386069)