# Ionic2 disables vertical swiping/dragging?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

So I started building a simple app in Ionic2 on Angular2. I ran into bugs quickly e.g. Angular2 uses Hammer.js for touch events handling, but it runs into an endless recursion because of a "typo". I found a comment on a github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6993#issuecomment-187115690
so I could fix this manually.

The next thing I found that whenever I try to `swipe` or `pan` down or up it won't fire the event, it works when I try to fire the events horizontally but not vertically.

`<ion-content (pan)="log($event)">...</ion-content>`

My questions are:

Is it really the Ionic2 implementation which causes the problem?
Is there a simple way to fix this?
Where should I find the corresponding source codes to edit?

Answer (score 0):

Hammer events are registered by Angular2 itself when the Hammer library is present. They can be used outside Ionic2.

Regarding code source codes, you could have a look at the following links:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser_common.ts#L79
- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/events/hammer_gestures.ts#L18

See also this question:

- [Configure Hammerjs events with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842552/configure-hammerjs-events-with-angular2/35845570#35845570)

Comment: Yes I know this, but as I mentioned it will fire horizontally, I guess Ionic2 blocks this vertically somehow. I mean you did not answer my question