# Set Short period in hammerjs requirefailure

Tags: javascript, web, hammer.js

How to set short period time interval or say, time for requirefailure in hammer.js. I know it wait for short period of time for another input but I want to change that time. So plese help me with that.

Comment: Please provide some more info what you are trying to achieve. What is your use case?

Comment: Lets talk about double click. In double click, you get a short period of time for another click after first click. I want to change that short period of time.

Comment: I'm not sure if  this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842552/configure-hammerjs-events-with-angular2) from SO is not relevant to your case. Also check this hummer [plugin](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer-time)