# Swiping to navigate from one component to another

Tags: angular, typescript

I am navigating from one component to another while swiping by using router.navigate(['/.article']); and hammerjs.

after swiped and navigate to another page, swipe is not fired without reloading the page

I need to do it without reloading the page

Thanks

Comment: please share the code and would be good if create a plnkr for this

Comment: sorry,I didn't created plunker.I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728451/using-mobile-events-in-angular2  for swiping.For navigation I used doSwipe(direction: string){
            
          if(direction=='swipeleft')
    {
    this. router.navigate(['/cinema']);
}
      
          }